# Check the Subject Field in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I see this code all over the internet and everyone says how wonderful it works but it doesn't for me, I'm clueless, any ideas why?
I have Windows 7 and Outlook 2010.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
 Dim strSubject As String
  strSubject = Item.Subject
     If Len(Trim(strSubject)) = 0 Then
         Prompt$ = "Subject is Empty. Are you sure you want to send the Mail?"
       If MsgBox(Prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check for Subject") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
      End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have set the correct references in your project for Outlook 2010 Library. Also ensure that Outlook 2010 should already be in running state. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for responding... reference to Outlook 14.0 Object Library is set. I do not understand your statement "Outlook 2010 should already be in running state", I do have Outlook started up and running.

Comment: Is it possible to post image of the exact error that you are getting or the text of the error. Thanks

Comment: I'm not getting an error, it just seems to not run the macro, I can post a JPEG image if I knew how, I'm not seeing that option here.

Comment: Is it possible to take a screen shot of the code and share. May be you can upload the file on some free file share website and share the URL here.

Comment: so what happens when you click send button in two scenarios i.e. 1) When you send email with subject 2) When you send email without subject.

Comment: Not sure if it means anything but another thing I noticed is that it's not showing up as a macro, take a look here [link](https://jumpshare.com/v/7cJmhxfNV5xEf71AOmoV)

Comment: Are your security settings for macros enabled? Is the Microsoft VBA for Outlook Addin loaded?

Comment: In Trust Center=> Macro Settings , ensure that macros are not disabled. So may be you can try by choosing "Enable All Macros" for testing  purpose only as this setting is not recommended for security threat reasons. Once your testing is completed, you can change it to another setting which is more acceptable in your environment. Please do not forget to shut down outlook and restart outlook every time you change this setting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you posted a link to a screen capture on May 20 at 16:04

go to that same place in the code and delete all the code in the sub, including sub and endsub (the code that you posted)

now click on "application" dropdown at top-left

you should see the following fill in

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub
```

if something else pops up, then click on ItemSend in dropdown on top right

put in one command to get this very minimal sub (if it does not work, then nothing else will)

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    msgbox "this works"

End Sub
```

now send any email, if it works then you should see a dialog box pop up

note: i have found that "just pasting in code" does not always work and you have to click on the dropdown menus, after you paste in the code, to get the sub to be registered